# Can't import json file using mongoimport

Tags: database, mongodb, import, mongoimport

I am trying to import a json file using mongoimport

```
mongoimport --db test --collection test1 --drop –file  ~/Downloads/data/data.json –jsonArray
```

it some times gives this error:
error parsing command line options: invalid argument for flag `/j, /numInsertionWorkers' (expected int): strconv.ParseInt: parsing "sonArray": invalid syntax

and sometimes this:
error validating settings: can not use --fields when input type is JSON

I am new to mongodbImport and i couldn't find any solution

Comment: no idea what that is

Answer (score 0):

You enter

```
mongoimport --db test --collection test1 --drop –file ~/Downloads/data/data.json –jsonArray
```

but it should be

```
mongoimport --db test --collection test1 --drop –file ~/Downloads/data/data.json --jsonArray
```

Note, you can use option `-j` or `--numInsertionWorkers=<number>`, however `-j` is not mentioned in [mongoimport documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/), you get it only from `mongoimport --help` command.

Comment: getting this error: can not use --fields when input type is JSON